# Can't get table to top of column

Tags: html, css

I have a table in "right column"  and I can't seem to get it to move to the top of that column. Any suggestions? I think it's something to do with css the display : `table-cell;`

link to fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZyAQc/

added link to fiddle so you can see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "vertical-align: top;" to #rightcolumn in your css

```
#rightcolumn{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%; /*Width of right column in pixels*/
    margin-left: -20%; /*Set margin to that of -(RightColumnWidth)*/
    background:#5f5f5f ;
    color: White;
}
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jqS8K/

Comment: lol glad it was easy :D  i thought i did that but anyhow works great. thanks

Comment: No problem, easy when you know how :D